# I want to display "how many times this tag used in Wordpress?"

Tags: plugins, tags

I am trying to make a simple site but I need a help.

2-3 page has a same tag eg: apple-2019-projects

And I want to display like that

[image]

Comment: Tags already work like that, don't they? So the bit you're missing is just a page that lists tags with counts? That's broadly [`wp_list_categories(show_count = 1)`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) although it might need some work to grouped in 'Apple' etc. as a top level with image and text as you've got here.

Comment: Thank you but I did not figure out. I will not use categories and  I want to display just specific tags in a POST PAGE not like whole site.  I am trying something like that first time.

Comment: So, in this page I want to display **apple-2019-projects** and **apple-2019-movies** tags. In another post I will show another tags eg. **huawei-2019-projects**